# With facebook graph API 4.0 How to programatically send friend requests between test users?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

This used to work years ago, but not anymore it seems. I'm using the facebook graph API to programatically generate test users and send/confirm friend requests.

It works creating test users:

User A

```
POST https://graph.facebook.com/v4.0/${APP-ID}/accounts/test-users HTTP/1.1 body{name=userA&access_token=${ACCESS-TOKEN}&installed=false}
RESPONSE: {“id":"106485800749210","login_url":"https:\/\/developers.facebook.com\/checkpoint\/test-user-login\/106485800749210\/?is_sandbox=0&sandbox_asset_type=test_user&page_id=0","email":"yciziemdeb_1568798987\u0040tfbnw.net","password":"1408448545"}

POST https://graph.facebook.com/v4.0/${APP-ID}/accounts/test-users HTTP/1.1 body{installed=true&permissions=email%2Cuser_friends&access_token=${ACCESS-TOKEN}&uid=106485800749210&owner_access_token=${OWNER-ACCESS-TOKEN}}
RESPONSE: {"id":"106485800749210","access_token":"******…","login_url":"https:\/\/developers.facebook.com\/checkpoint\/test-user-login\/106485800749210\/?is_sandbox=0&sandbox_asset_type=test_user&page_id=0","email":"yciziemdeb_1568798987\u0040tfbnw.net"}
```

User B

```
POST https://graph.facebook.com/v4.0/${APP-ID}/accounts/test-users HTTP/1.1 body{name=userB&access_token=${ACCESS-TOKEN}&installed=false}
RESPONSE: {"id":"113912670000851","login_url":"https:\/\/developers.facebook.com\/checkpoint\/test-user-login\/113912670000851\/?is_sandbox=0&sandbox_asset_type=test_user&page_id=0","email":"pmztcoojcx_1568799008\u0040tfbnw.net","password":"2095538830"}

POST https://graph.facebook.com/v4.0/${APP-ID} accounts/test-users HTTP/1.1 body{installed=true&permissions=email+user_friends&access_token=${ACCESS-TOKEN}&uid=113912670000851&owner_access_token=${OWNER-ACCESS-TOKEN}}
RESPONSE: {"id":"113912670000851","access_token":"******…","login_url":"https:\/\/developers.facebook.com\/checkpoint\/test-user-login\/113912670000851\/?is_sandbox=0&sandbox_asset_type=test_user&page_id=0","email":"pmztcoojcx_1568799008\u0040tfbnw.net"}
```

But fails when sending friend request:

```
POST https://graph.facebook.com/v4.0/106485800749210/friends/113912670000851 HTTP/1.1 body{access_token=${USER.A-ACCESS-TOKEN}}
RESPONSE: Bad Request : {"error":{"message":"(#33) This object does not exist or does not support this action","type":"OAuthException","code":33,"fbtrace_id":"AhXLj4h44ydX3n0dsJO4Dj5"}}
```

What am I doing wrong? Here is the documentation for facebook graph API  */{user-id}/friends* edge:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v4.0/test-user/friends